# Python checking if line above or below equals to phrase

Tags: python, ocr

I am trying to make an **automated monthly cost calculator** for my family. The idea is whenever they shop they take a **picture of the receipt** and **send it to an e-mail adress**. A Python script **downloads that picture** and using the **Google Vision API** scans for the **Total amount** which then **gets written into a .csv file for later use**. ( I have yet to make the csv thing so it's only being saved into txts for now.)

This works because in my country the receipts all look the same because of regulations however the Google Vision API returns the OCRed text back line by line. What i am trying to do now is check the text line by line for the total amount which is always in the following format (Numbers space Currency) then i check if the OCR messed up something like put the "Total amount" above or below the actual numbers.

*My problem is that if i run this script on more than 3 .txt OCR data then it only gets the first 2 right even though they are the same if i manually check them. If i run it on them 1 by 1 then it gets them perfect everytime.*

The OCR data looks like this:

Total amount:

1000 USD

or

1000 USD

Total amount:

My code so far:

```
import re
import os
import codecs

for files in os.listdir('texts/'):
   filedir="texts/"+str(files)
   with codecs.open(filedir,'rb','utf-8') as f:
      lines=f.readlines()
      lines=[l.strip() for l in lines]
      for index,line in enumerate(lines):
         match=re.search(r"(\d+) USD",line)
         if match:
            if lines[index+1].endswith("USD"):
               amount=re.sub(r'(\d\s+(\d)',r'\1\2',lines[index])
               amount=amount.replace(" USD","")
               print(amount)
               with open('amount.txt',"a") as data:
                    data.write(amount)
                    data.write("\n")
             if lines[index-1].endswith("USD"):
               amount=re.sub(r'(\d\s+(\d)',r'\1\2',lines[index])
               amount=amount.replace(" USD","")
               print(amount)
               with open('amount.txt',"a") as data:
                    data.write(amount)
                    data.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: checking if line above or below equals to phrase

Simplify to the following:

> **Assumptions**:
>
> 1. The Amount line has the following format (Numbers space Currency).
> 2. These exact phrase `"Total amount:"`, exists allways in the other line.
> 3. The above lines are separated with a blank line.

```
FILE1 = u"""Total amount:

1000 USD
"""
FILE2 = u"""1000 USD

Total amount:"""

import io
import os
import codecs

total = []
#for files in os.listdir('texts/'):
for files in [FILE1, FILE2]:
    # filedir="texts/"+str(files)
    # with codecs.open(filedir,'rb','utf-8') as f:
    with io.StringIO(files) as f:
        v1 = next(f).rstrip()
        # eat empty line
        next(f)
        v2 = next(f).rstrip()

        if v1 == 'Total amount:':
            total.append(v2.split()[0]) 
        else:
            total.append(v1.split()[0]) 

print(total)
# csv_writer.writerows(total)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> [u'1000', u'1000']
> ```